# Aggregating multiple rasters within a polygon in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, sql, spatial-join

I have several raster tables in PostGIS (four in fact but in this case let us assume there are just two) - same cell sizes, same alignment but with different types of value (e.g 3d_pot, 3d_area). Occasionally there will be -9999 values where data is missing but this might not be the case in all three datasets for the same cell (e.g. there could be 3d_pot but not 3d_area).

I want to calculate the aggregate statistics for all the cells that are within a polygon (e.g. a building footprint) but only for those cells where 3d_pot is greater than a value (say 100).

For one value I need to calculate a combination of the cell values at the same location (3d_area * 3d_pot).

I'm struggling to find a fast way to effectively join the rasters based upon their spatial location, having intersected with the polygon layer and ignore all cells if one of them is -9999.

What is the simplest SQL way of doing this on the fly (without generating new rasters or rasterizing the building polygons?)

Here is what I currently have but this feels wrong and excessive to do multiple Intersections. Can you join one raster to another just using the raster geometry?

```
WITH solarpot AS (
SELECT fid, 
    (ST_Intersection(T.wkb_geometry, ST_Clip(ST_MapAlgebra(AREA.rast,POT.rast,'([rast2])',NULL,'INTERSECTION'), 1, T.wkb_geometry, True))).val AS potval,
    (ST_Intersection(T.wkb_geometry, ST_Clip(ST_MapAlgebra(AREA.rast,POT.rast,'([rast1])',NULL,'INTERSECTION'), 1, T.wkb_geometry, True))).val AS areaval,
    (ST_Intersection(T.wkb_geometry, ST_Clip(ST_MapAlgebra(AREA.rast,POT.rast,'([rast1]*[rast2])',NULL,'INTERSECTION'), 1, T.wkb_geometry, True))).val AS sumpotval
   FROM solar_rasters.solarp_3d_area AREA
   JOIN os_gla.topographicarea T ON ST_Intersects(T.wkb_geometry, AREA.rast)
   JOIN solar_rasters.solarp_3d_pot POT ON ST_Intersects(T.wkb_geometry, POT.rast)
   WHERE T.fid = 'osgb5000005156542071'
)
SELECT fid, COUNT(potval), SUM(potval), SUM(areaval) AS sumareaval, SUM(sumpotval) AS sumpotval, AVG(potval), stddev(potval), MIN(potval), MAX(potval)
FROM solarpot
WHERE potval IS NOT NULL AND potval >= 100 AND areaval IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY fid
```

Comment: Are your rasters tiled?

Comment: Yes the are:
`raster2pgsql -s 27700 -t 100x100 -I -C -M`

Answer (score 0):

So I have currently done this by just making a JOIN on the raster geometry and this seems to work reasonably well (given the size of the rasters). If I am missing something basic and there is a much faster way to do this it would be good to know:

```
-- this works and seems to get us correct values
WITH solarpot AS (
   SELECT fid, 
    (ST_Intersection(T.wkb_geometry, ST_Clip(POT.rast, 1, T.wkb_geometry, True))).* as geom

   FROM solar_rasters.solarp_3d_pot POT
   JOIN os_gla.topographicarea T ON ST_Intersects(T.wkb_geometry, POT.rast)
   WHERE T.fid = 'osgb1000005305136'
),
area AS (
   SELECT fid, 
    (ST_Intersection(T.wkb_geometry, ST_Clip(AREA.rast, 1, T.wkb_geometry, True))).* as geom

   FROM solar_rasters.solarp_3d_area AREA
   JOIN os_gla.topographicarea T ON ST_Intersects(T.wkb_geometry, AREA.rast)
   WHERE T.fid = 'osgb1000005305136'
),
tilt AS (
   SELECT fid, 
    (ST_Intersection(T.wkb_geometry, ST_Clip(TILT.rast, 1, T.wkb_geometry, True))).* as geom

   FROM solar_rasters.solarp_3d_tilt TILT
   JOIN os_gla.topographicarea T ON ST_Intersects(T.wkb_geometry, TILT.rast)
   WHERE T.fid = 'osgb1000005305136'
),
azi AS (
   SELECT fid, 
    (ST_Intersection(T.wkb_geometry, ST_Clip(AZI.rast, 1, T.wkb_geometry, True))).* as geom

   FROM solar_rasters.solarp_3d_azi AZI
   JOIN os_gla.topographicarea T ON ST_Intersects(T.wkb_geometry, AZI.rast)
   WHERE T.fid = 'osgb1000005305136'
)
SELECT SP.fid, SP.val AS potval, A.val AS area3d, TI.val AS tilt, AZ.val AS azi
FROM solarpot SP 
JOIN area A ON SP.geom = A.geom
JOIN tilt TI ON SP.geom = TI.geom
JOIN azi AZ ON SP.geom = AZ.geom
WHERE SP.val > 500
```